# How to determine the maximum color in an image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a picture box in C# application.

I want to determine the color from the image, which is in the maximum amount, i.e. the color which covers the maximum area of the image.
Is there any third party tool available which can help me to do so?

Comment: Look up "histogram" tools and libraries. These are designed to show color usage throughout an image and show relative quantities.

Comment: @Tanuj Wadhawa Did my answer provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a 256*256*256 int array for storing all number of occurences of the RGB value of each point in the picture, will take 64 MB of space and some iteration.

something like:

```
occurences = int[256][256][256] 
for x in picture.width()
    for y in picture.height()
        p = point(x,y) in picture;
        occurences[p.red][p.blue][p.green]++;

Find max value in occurences
```

Comment: A hashmap/dictionary would be useful if you know the set of different colors is limited (i.e. if it not a photo).

Comment: This is quite trivial approach. You should not to create such big array. Better calculate the integer and use a hash map for it. the color value can be easily calculated by shifting red 16 bits, green 8 bits and then add all them.